# Issue when trying to interact with an API in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

**datalist.js**

```html
import axios from "axios";

export const datalist = () => {
  return axios.get("myapiurl/name...").then((response) => response);
};
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.DttID">
      <router-link
        :to="{
          name: 'UserWithID',
          params: { id: item.DepaD },
          query: { DepaD: item.DepaID },
        }"
      >
        <div class="bt-color">{{ item.DepaName }}</div>
      </router-link>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <User />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import User from "./User.vue";
import { datalist } from "./datalist";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    User,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: datalist,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    datalist().then((r) => {
      this.items = r.data;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

**User.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, key) in user" :key="key">
      {{ item.Accv }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { datalist } from "./datalist";
export default {
  name: "User",
  data() {
    return {
      lists: datalist,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    user: function () {
      return this.lists.filter((item) => {
        if (item.DepaD === this.$route.params.id) {
          return item;
        }
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Error with the code is,

**[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.lists.filter is not a function"
TypeError: this.lists.filter is not a function**

The above error i am getting in User.vue component in the line number '20'

From the api which is in, datalist.js file, i think i am not fetching data correctly. or in the list filter there is problem in User.vue?

Comment: datalist is a function that returns a promise. You never call the function + you dont use the promise :)

Comment: I do have network errors on your snippet (probably the backend service is not accessible)

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash  Now it is working fine. Without any network issues. But some new problem comes with routerlink like... Onclick of router-link ,i am getting the appropriate content. But after clicking router-link if i refresh the page, in the url section i can see the previously clickedd url/id but content is disapperead.(Is there anyway to solve it)

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash Sry, Can you please delete the sandbox, as it contain my api url ..... where it is confidential....

Comment: @Sundar yes sure deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the following

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
data() {
  return {
    items: [],
  };
},
mounted() {
  datalist().then((r) => {
    this.items = r.data;
  });
},
```

**User.vue**

```
data() {
  return {
    lists: []
  };
},
mounted() {
  datalist().then((r) => {
    this.lists = r.data;
  });
},
```

At least this suppress the error, but i cant tell more based on your snippet since there are network issues :)

Comment: Now it is working fine. Without any network issues. But some problem with routerlink like...

Onclick of router-link ,i am getting the appropriate content. But after clicking router-link if i refresh the page, in the url section i can see the previously clickedd **url/id** but content is disapperead. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since your datalist function returns a Promise, you need to wait for it to complete. To do this, simply modify your component code as follows:

```
import { datalist } from "./datalist";
export default {
  name: "User",
  data() {
    return {
      // empty array on initialization
      lists: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    user: function() {
      return this.lists.filter((item) => {
        if (item.DeploymentID === this.$route.params.id) {
          return item;
        }
      });
    },
  },
  // asynchronous function - because internally we are waiting for datalist() to complete
  async-mounted() {
    this.users = await datalist() // or datalist().then(res => this.users = res) - then async is not needed
  }
};
```

now there will be no errors when initializing the component, since initially lists is an empty array but after executing the request it will turn into what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now problem with routerlink like... Onclick of router-link ,i am getting the appropriate content. But after clicking router-link if i refresh the page, in the url section i can see the previously clickedd url/id but content is disapperead. Dont know why.

Comment: For this solution, Do i need to use vuex for state management or any alternative ways?

To maintain page data, even after page refreshed?

Comment: Firstly, you should check the components in your router configuration for each path. Secondly, please ensure that the component which is rendered now downloads correct data via the network. To check which component appears on your page now, I recommend to use the Vuejs Chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg?hl=en-US

Answer (score 0):

You may define any functions and import them, but they wont affect until you call them, in this case we have `datalist` function imported in both `HelloWorld` and `User` component, but it did not been called in `User` component. so your code:

```
  data() {
    return {
      lists: datalist,
    };
  },
```

cause `lists` to be equal to `datalist` that is a **function**, no an **array**! where `.filter()` should be used after an **array**, not a **function**! that is the reason of error.
thus you should call function `datalist` and put it's response in `lists` instead of putting `datalist` itself in `lists`

Extra:

- it is better to call axios inside the component, in `mounted`, `created` or ...
- it is not good idea to call an axios command twice, can call it in `HelloWorl` component and pass it to `User` component via `props`